# iPhone App for Stereo Audio Recording

Tags: ios, audio, iphone-app, voice-recording, audio-editing

I want to record some audio books on iPhone. I have tried several recording apps, however all of them give me a mono audio file which is a bit annoying when you listen to it with headphones, as there's no sound on one side. This can be simply fixed but adding the same layer of the audio to the other channel so that it makes it stereo, however I haven't found an app (ideally free) that has these features together:

1. Pause feature rather than just stop and save the file
2. Stereo recording
3. Trim, cut, paste

I have tried iTalk, Voice Record, HandyRec., and a few more in addition to the memo recorder (original recording app). Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you using to play back the audio? This seems like a problem with the player rather than the recorder. Recording in mono is correct, since the iPhone uses one microphone to record, so recording in stereo would be a waste of space. It is up to the player to output the same audio stream to both channels when encountering a mono audio file. This is a very basic "feature" of any audio player I would think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Hokusai Audio Editor](https://itunes.apple.com/ie/app/hokusai-audio-editor/id432079746?mt=8) and [WavePad Music and Audio Editor](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wavepad-music-and-audio-editor/id395339564?mt=8) were the two apps that I found and have been using whenever needed. They're both quite good but with room for improvements. They do the job for me and have the features I'd been looking for.